# Make the Linear Discriminant Analysis to run

Tags: r

I'm trying to make my Linear Discriminant Analysis work. I'm trying to run:

```
set.seed(2018)

n <- nrow(<dataset>)

shuffled <- <dataset>[sample(n),]

training <- shuffled[1:round(0.7 * n),]
testing<- shuffled[(round(0.7 * n) + 1):n,]

lda.fit=lda(y ~.,data = training)

summary(lda.fit)

lda.pred=predict(lda.fit,training)

lda.class=lda.pred$class

table(lda.class,testing)

mean(lda.class)
```

When running the `table-function`, I get the error:

```
"Error in table(lda.class, banktrain) : 
  all arguments must have the same length".
```

What to do?

Comment: n <- nrow(<dataset>)
shuffled <- <dataset>[sample(n),]

training <- shuffled[1:round(0.5 * n),]
testing<- shuffled[(round(0.5 * n) + 1):n,]

Comment: When running the dput(training) I get ......21940L, 6583L, 33041L, 6021L, 40968L, 6537L, 9505L), class = "data.frame")
Think it is all my observations.

Comment: I guess the error is saying that the number of rows differs in *lda.class* and *testing*. You have used predict on training data, so shouldn't you use the training data in a table too instead of testing?

Comment: I'm getting the same result with training.

Comment: try doing `table(lda.class,training$y)`

Comment: it's more than 40.000 observations..

Comment: IT WORKED! WOOOHOOOO <3 
Thanks mate!

Comment: But, another problem. i can't use the testing data now..

Comment: If you use predict on training set then you should also use training set to evaluate the accuracy and vice versa (you should use predict on test data then only you would be able to use testing data).

Comment: > train=(Year <2005)
> Smarket .2005= Smarket [!train ,]
I found out that this are the differences in my code. What does this mean?